# Confusion about the use of the possessive in the field name "Women's studies"

Tags: possessives

Why does the field *Women's studies* take the possessive *s*?

And why is it not the case for "Archaeological studies", for example?

Comment: A conjuncture, because that's what this sort of question calls for: presumably because there doesn't exist a satisfactory enough adjective (*womanly studies*?), unlike in the latter case. The alternatives, therefore, become *effectively* restricted to *women studies* and *women's studies*. And now the choice between the two is arbitrary. Perhaps *woman studies* and *woman's studies* are also eligible competitors.

Comment: The way I understand it is that *women's studies* is the field/subject that only women can be part of/are allowed to take.

Comment: @Norbert Nah, anyone can take a women’s studies course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The examples are structurally different. "Archaeological" is an adjective, and it modifies "studies."

> - Archaeological studies = Studies related to archaeology
> - Experimental physics = Physics studied by performing and analyzing experiments (as opposed to theoretical physics)
> - Organic chemistry = Chemistry of organic compounds

All three cases have an adjective followed by a noun.

"Women" is a noun, not an adjective. In this case, we are using the possessive to act like an adjective.

> - Women's studies = Studies of subjects related to women.
> - Women's rights = The rights of women.

As best I can tell, this is a unique case. There is no adjective that means "concerning / related to women." The word *feminine* fails because it means "having qualities commonly associated with women," so that "feminine studies" sounds like the study itself *is* feminine; but men can pursue women's studies. (However, contrast with *feminine hygiene*.) Likewise, "womanly" and "female" fail, the latter because it suggests a study of the gender itself rather than of peripheral subjects experienced by or concerning women.